Terraform Resource Delete
How can I destroy or create resources that are dependent on one another? For example, I want to delete the AWS Network Firewall, but it cannot be deleted because its Endpoint is already in use in the route table, and I also can't delete the Firewall policy because the RuleGroup attached to it is already in use.
How can I delete a resource without manual intervention and create one with manual intervention?
resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "example" {
  name         = "Domains"
  tags         = {}
  tags_all     = {}
  firewall_policy {
    stateful_default_actions           = [
      "aws:alert_strict",
      "aws:drop_established",
    ]

    stateless_default_actions          = [
      "aws:forward_to_sfe",
    ]

    stateless_fragment_default_actions = [
      "aws:pass",
    ]

    stateful_engine_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }

    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      priority     = 3
      resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:ap-
southeast-2:123456789:stateful-rulegroup/example-TEST"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall" "example" {
  name                = "NFWtf"
  firewall_policy_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:ap-
southeast-2:1234567890:firewall-policy/nfw"
  vpc_id              = "vpc-ftyha9po1"
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = "subnet-0022444rr138bc6"
  }

  tags = {
    Tag1 = "Value1"
    Tag2 = "Value2"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "40m"
    update = "50m"
    delete = "1h"
  }
}

How I can fix this?

To avoid such situations in terraform you would use either implicit or explicit dependencies. Implicit dependencies are created when one resource references an attribute from a different resource, and attributes are accessible only after a resource has been created. That way terraform knows the exact order in which to create and delete resources. So in your case, the code block you added to the question should be modified to look something like the following (note that one resource is missing in your question):
resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "example" {
  name         = "Domains"
  tags         = {}
  tags_all     = {}
  firewall_policy {
    stateful_default_actions           = [
      "aws:alert_strict",
      "aws:drop_established",
    ]

    stateless_default_actions          = [
      "aws:forward_to_sfe",
    ]

    stateless_fragment_default_actions = [
      "aws:pass",
    ]

    stateful_engine_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }

    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      priority     = 3
      resource_arn = aws_networkfirewall_rule_group.example.arn # this resource is missing from the question, so it's just a guess
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall" "example" {
  name                = "NFWtf"
  firewall_policy_arn = aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy.example.arn
  vpc_id              = "vpc-ftyha9po1"
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = "subnet-0022444rr138bc6"
  }

  tags = {
    Tag1 = "Value1"
    Tag2 = "Value2"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "40m"
    update = "50m"
    delete = "1h"
  }
}


Many Thanks,    So I can add the Routing block in the same way, but because Firewall EndPoints are present in the route table,So I can't delete the firewall until I delete the routes that use Firewall EndPoints as Nexthops.                                 resource "aws_route" "NATGW-to-FW" {
route_table_id            = "rtb-96atghif0"
destination_cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
vpc_endpoint_id = "vpce-123456789"
}

I don't see how this route that you've added in the comment is related to the OP. It has no reference of the AWS Firewall as far as I can see.
